# Ruby: creating a case statement that checks csv file for string to authenticate user (terminal only)

Tags: ruby

I apologies if this is simple but I'm just starting out. Any constructive help welcome.

Problem:

- Trying to create authentication from ruby terminal to CSV.
- I'd like to create clean (and as short as possible) loop statement that goes to csv file checks the top row for header "pin" and then checks the gets.chomp entry against that to authenticate.

  ```
  require 'csv'

  class Menu

    def self.login
      system "clear"
      puts "Welcome to Hip-Bikes & Coffee"
      puts "Please login with your pin:"
      print "> "
      customer_pin = gets.chomp

      verified = authentication(customer_pin)
    end

    def self.authentication(customer_pin)

      case
      when CSV.foreach('customers.csv', headers: true) { |row| ["pin"] == login.verified }
        puts verified
      else
        puts "login failed. Please try again in 3 seconds..."
        sleep(3.0)
        self.login
  ```

Comment: Can you add a few strings from csv?

Comment: Hi Alex, apologies but what exactly are you after?

Comment: not sure what you mean but I plan on authenticating using a randomly generated pin for each user. so \\for arguments sake we can use "1234" - hope thats what you needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you

***UPD***

```
 require 'csv'

class Menu
  class << self
    def login
      login_start
      verified(gets.chomp)
    end

    def verified(input)
      if authentication(input)
        puts 'verified'
      else
        failed
      end
    end

    def authentication(customer_pin)
      CSV.foreach('customers.csv', headers: true).any? { |row| row['pin'] == customer_pin }
    end

    def failed
      puts "login failed. Please try again in 3 seconds..."
      sleep(3.0)
      login
    end

    def login_start
      system "clear"
      print "Welcome to Hip-Bikes & Coffee\nPlease login with your pin:\n> "
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks Alex!

Comment: @AlexGoludenko sorry but that last one doesn't work. am I missing something?

Comment: sorry I just re-added it and now it works. Must have been an error on my part. Could I ask... how is the case statement seeing verified - the get.chomp input?

Comment: @PaulThompson little bit bad understand your question "how is the case statement seeing verified - the gets.chomp input?"

Comment: Im a beginner so probably my words. I think I actually have it (what you did / changed) now just didn't know you could do it that way. Thanks again!